# Supervisor couldn't chdir to directory. ENOENT error

Tags: bash, supervisord, enoent

I can't start a process because this error is hurting me. I tried to find any information and **[he](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/1489#issuecomment-1017734171)** says that it means there is no directory, but it is there. User "rafail" has permission to interact with the directory.

**Here is logs:**

```
supervisor: couldn't chdir to ~/MyProjects/PhoneNumbers_Sender/: ENOENT
supervisor: child process was not spawned
supervisor: couldn't chdir to ~/MyProjects/PhoneNumbers_Sender/: ENOENT
supervisor: child process was not spawned
supervisor: couldn't chdir to ~/MyProjects/PhoneNumbers_Sender/: ENOENT
supervisor: child process was not spawned
supervisor: couldn't chdir to ~/MyProjects/PhoneNumbers_Sender/: ENOENT
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

**And my project configuration file:**

```
[program:phone_sender]                                                      
directory=~/MyProjects/PhoneNumbers_Sender/
command=bash start.sh
user=rafail
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=0
stderr_logfile=~/phone_stderr.log
stdout_logfile=~/phone_stdout.log
```

*PS. I work with supervisor for the first time and I try to understand it. Thank you for understanding.*

Comment: Is it possible that `~` is not being expanded correctly by supervisord?  What happens if you specify the directory and log files by their full paths instead of with `~`?

Comment: I will try to do it, but I think that is not a really reason, because logging files was created successfully with `~`. Thank you!

Comment: @dg99 God damn... You was right :D Thank you <3